How to Configure TAPI to Control Avaya IP Office Calls?
Goal:
I am developing a C++ application using TAPI (Telephony Application Programming Interface) to control calls on an Avaya IP Office system. The primary objective is to programmatically monitor and route incoming calls to specific extensions in real-time based on predefined logic.
Current Progress:

I have successfully set up the TAPI 3.0 configuration and can fetch all the extensions from the Avaya IP Office system.
I can initialize TAPI and interact with the Avaya IP Office using the provided drivers.

What I Want to Achieve:
1. Monitor specific extensions for incoming call events, such as LINECALLSTATE_OFFERING.
2. Programmatically route calls to different extensions based on business logic.

Issue:
While I can successfully retrieve extensions from Avaya IP Office, I am unable to monitor events on these extensions. Even when making calls to a monitored extension, no events are being received.
Code I Am Using to Monitor an Extension:
#include <tapi3.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <string>

// Forward declarations
HRESULT CheckTAPIConfiguration(ITTAPI* pTapi);
ITAddress* GetSpecificExtension(ITTAPI* pTapi, const std::wstring& targetExtension);

// Custom event handler class
class MyTapiEventHandler : public ITTAPIEventNotification {
private:
    ULONG m_refCount;

public:
    MyTapiEventHandler() : m_refCount(1) {}

    // IUnknown methods
    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppvObject) {
        if (riid == IID_IUnknown || riid == IID_ITTAPIEventNotification) {
            *ppvObject = static_cast<ITTAPIEventNotification*>(this);
            AddRef();
            return S_OK;
        }
        *ppvObject = nullptr;
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }

    ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef() {
        return InterlockedIncrement(&m_refCount);
    }

    ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release() {
        ULONG count = InterlockedDecrement(&m_refCount);
        if (count == 0) {
            delete this;
        }
        return count;
    }

    // ITTAPIEventNotification method
    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Event(TAPI_EVENT tapiEvent, IDispatch* pEvent) {
        std::wcout << L"Received TAPI event: " << tapiEvent << std::endl;

        if (tapiEvent == TE_CALLNOTIFICATION) {
            ITCallNotificationEvent* pCallNotification = nullptr;
            HRESULT hr = pEvent->QueryInterface(IID_ITCallNotificationEvent, (void**)&pCallNotification);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                ITCallInfo* pCallInfo = nullptr;
                hr = pCallNotification->get_Call(&pCallInfo);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                    BSTR callerId;
                    hr = pCallInfo->get_CallInfoString(CIS_CALLERIDNUMBER, &callerId);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && callerId) {
                        std::wcout << L"Incoming call from: " << callerId << std::endl;
                        SysFreeString(callerId);
                    }
                    pCallInfo->Release();
                }
                pCallNotification->Release();
            }
        }

        return S_OK;
    }
};

int main() {
    HRESULT hr;

    // Initialize COM library
    hr = CoInitialize(nullptr);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cerr << "COM library initialization failed!" << std::endl;
        return hr;
    }

    ITTAPI* pTapi = nullptr;

    // Create TAPI 3.0 COM object
    hr = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_TAPI,
        nullptr,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_ITTAPI,
        (void**)&pTapi
    );

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create TAPI 3.0 object!" << std::endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return hr;
    }

    // Initialize TAPI
    hr = pTapi->Initialize();
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cerr << "TAPI initialization failed!" << std::endl;
        pTapi->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return hr;
    }

    // Check TAPI configuration
    hr = CheckTAPIConfiguration(pTapi);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        pTapi->Shutdown();
        pTapi->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return hr;
    }

    // Specify the target extension to monitor
    std::wstring targetExtension = L"5002"; // Change this to your desired extension
    ITAddress* pSpecificAddress = GetSpecificExtension(pTapi, targetExtension);

    if (pSpecificAddress) {
        std::wcout << L"Monitoring extension: " << targetExtension << std::endl;

        // Register for call notifications
        long lRegister = 0;
        VARIANT_BOOL fMonitor = VARIANT_TRUE;
        VARIANT_BOOL fOwner = VARIANT_TRUE;
        long lMediaTypes = TAPIMEDIATYPE_AUDIO;
        long lCallbackInstance = 0;

        hr = pTapi->RegisterCallNotifications(
            pSpecificAddress, fMonitor, fOwner, lMediaTypes, lCallbackInstance, &lRegister
        );

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
            std::wcout << L"Call notification registered successfully. Registration ID: " << lRegister << std::endl;
            std::wcout << L"Monitoring calls... Press 'q' and Enter to quit." << std::endl;

            while (true) {
                if (GetAsyncKeyState('Q') & 0x8000) {
                    std::wcout << L"Exiting monitoring loop." << std::endl;
                    break;
                }
                Sleep(100); // Small delay to reduce CPU usage
            }
        } else {
            std::wcerr << L"Failed to register call notifications. HRESULT: " << std::hex << hr << std::endl;
        }

        pSpecificAddress->Release();
    } else {
        std::wcout << L"Extension not found: " << targetExtension << std::endl;
    }

    // Shutdown TAPI
    pTapi->Shutdown();
    pTapi->Release();
    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}

// Function to check TAPI configuration
HRESULT CheckTAPIConfiguration(ITTAPI* pTapi) {
    IEnumAddress* pEnumAddress = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = pTapi->EnumerateAddresses(&pEnumAddress);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::wcerr << L"Failed to enumerate TAPI addresses. HRESULT: " << std::hex << hr << std::endl;
        return hr;
    }

    ITAddress* pAddress = nullptr;
    ULONG fetched = 0;
    if (pEnumAddress->Next(1, &pAddress, &fetched) != S_OK) {
        std::wcerr << L"No TAPI addresses found. TAPI might not be configured." << std::endl;
        pEnumAddress->Release();
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    std::wcout << L"TAPI is configured and addresses are available." << std::endl;
    pAddress->Release();
    pEnumAddress->Release();
    return S_OK;
}

// Function to find a specific extension by name
ITAddress* GetSpecificExtension(ITTAPI* pTapi, const std::wstring& targetExtension) {
    IEnumAddress* pEnumAddress = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = pTapi->EnumerateAddresses(&pEnumAddress);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to enumerate addresses." << std::endl;
        return nullptr;
    }

    ITAddress* pAddress = nullptr;
    ULONG fetched = 0;
    bool found = false;

    while (pEnumAddress->Next(1, &pAddress, &fetched) == S_OK) {
        BSTR bstrAddressName = nullptr;
        hr = pAddress->get_AddressName(&bstrAddressName);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && bstrAddressName != nullptr) {
            std::wstring addressName(bstrAddressName, SysStringLen(bstrAddressName));
            SysFreeString(bstrAddressName);
            std::wcout << L"Found extension: " << addressName << std::endl;

            // Check if this is the target extension
            if (addressName.find(targetExtension) != std::wstring::npos) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        pAddress->Release();
    }

    pEnumAddress->Release();
    return found ? pAddress : nullptr;
}

Questions:
1. How can I ensure that events (e.g., incoming call notifications) are properly received for monitored extensions?
2. Are there additional configurations or settings required in Avaya IP Office to allow TAPI events to be triggered?
3. Is there an alternative or recommended approach to monitor and handle events for specific extensions?

Additional Information:
1. I have verified that TAPI 3.0 is properly configured and working as expected with Avaya IP Office.
2. No errors are being thrown in the current setup, but no events are being received during testing.
3. The Avaya TAPI driver is correctly installed and configured, and all extensions are being fetched successfully.

I would appreciate any insights or guidance on how to resolve this issue and properly monitor events for extensions. Thank you!

Please update your question to include the exact errors you are getting. Also, have you read Avaya's TAPI documentation?

Actually i was trying some code which i have collected from online sources, but i am at stage 0. I have gone through the documentation but it has no explanation on how to create connection and control the call.

"a step-by-step guide or any resources" - asking for tutorials and offsite resources is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Conceptually, you are looking at a structure of drivers having devices having addresses. But all devices from all drivers are in just one big list numbered 0 to dwNumDevs (what you got back from LineInitializeEx()).
So, you don't yet know which devices belong to your Avaya. Usually, the OS has several built-in devices taking up the first few slots. Your errors are probably from trying to access these. You first need to look through the device list to find the ones you want.
Use lineGetDevCaps() to ask details for each device in the list. You want to look at field like DeviceName and ProviderInfo to spot your extensions. Only then do you know which devices to use for lineOpen().
Please note that if you are doing this from C++, you need to negotiate the 2.2 version, not the 3.0 version (3.x uses COM).

i am using TAPI3 as per now and i have successfully made the connection to the AVAYA IPO. I am now able to get the devices list that are available in IPO but now I am struggling with the monitoring that extension.
